# Are there benefits to re-defining JSON data as JavaScript objects in source code?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm loading a JSON file from a web server via the `XMLHttpRequest` in JavaScript. This module, or alternatively the `JSON.parse` method, returns a `JSON Object` (a regular JavaScript object, which I call JSON Object as [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) does).

Loaded JSON data:

```
{
    "MyName":"Kiwi",
    "MyNum" : "42",
    "MyList" : {
    "$type" :"Bla",
    "$values: [ ]
    }
};
```

I can pass around the parsed object and access it's properties like a regular JavaScript object. However, I'm wondering if it would make sense to actually declare the object's properties in source code such as:

```
// MyObject.js
function MyObject() {
    this.myName = "Kiwi";
    this.myNum = 42;
    this.myList = []
}
```

And basically, map each property from my parsed JSON object to the JavaScript object declared in source code like so (plus additional transformations):

```
var myObj = new MyObject();
myObj.myName = jsonObject.MyName;
myObj.myNum = jsonObject.MyNum;
```

I would assume this has benefits such as:

1. Actual type information such as numbers vs strings
2. Potentially intellisense/auto-complete features in my IDE
3. Easier upgrading of data, if the JSON properties ever change

I'm comparing my approach to how JSON is parsed and turned into objects in a language such as C#, using a serializer such as JSON.NET.

Is this also common practice in the JavaScript world or should I stick to just using the JSON objects returned by the JSON.parse method?

---

Further info:
My special use-case is the handling of JSON data, which includes many meta fields (denoted by names such as "$type" or "$values" to indicate an array). The files were created by JSON.NET and serialize C# objects, which I basically mirror in my JavaScript application. Hence, I might want to re-declare properties more similar to the way the original C# classes were declared. Mainly this would turn calls like `myObject.aList.$values[0]` into `myObject.aList[0]`.

Comment: *"I can pass around the parsed object and access it's properties like a regular JavaScript object."* -- there is no such thing as *"JSON object"* or *"JSON array"*. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. In order to use the data one have to parse the JSON and what they get back is a data structure specific to the language that replicates the original date structure used to create the JSON. In JavaScript, those data structures specific to the language are exactly the JavaScript array and object.

Comment: The object that `JSON.parse` returns behaves exactly like a regular JavaScript object because **it is a regular JavaScript object** and nothing else.

Comment: 4. Methods from `MyObject.prototype`?!

Comment: It does not make sense to define the object explicitly with a function. The result would be exactly the same as what you get from JSON.parse.

Comment: Per the update: if you're transforming the object structure as you go, then sure, that's a benefit.  Other than that, this would just add a layer of indirection to what is already a javascript object; if you really prefer the `new Foo` syntax it wouldn't do much harm.

Comment: I've added further explanation to may post, where I try to clarify, that the object resulting from JSON.parse is slightly different from the one I would ideally define myself because of the way the original serializer created the JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

If you need more than the data types JSON provides, you can roll something yourself to process the items that `JSON.parse` spits out, or use many libraries [like this one](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-js)

Most peoples use cases are simple enough that they won't need a library that supports more 'rich' data storage, and JSON is fine.

If you know the data structure ahead of time, and need to convert for example a JSON date (stored as a string) into a Javascript date, it's best to just convert it upon loading the JSON. If you have complex needs requiring loading complex data types that you won't be able to predict ahead of time, use a library like Transit.js

Comment: Another option is to use some kind of encoding like base64 strings for things like audio files or images